# How to run rendering thread properly from class with function inside that class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml

I have this error at my project with threads and I dont know how to solve it. I tryed std::thread and sf::Thread. Could someone help please?

Im creating Animation object inside main class and through function runThread() I am trying to launch thread inside the Animation class.

Error log:
Failed to activate the window's context
Failed to activate OpenGL context

My solution
Main class

```
int main()
{
    bool launchThreads = true;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode( 800, 600), "Title" );


    Animation* anima = new Animation(window);
    

    sf::Event event;
    while(window.isOpen())
    { 
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            anima->handleEvent(event);
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                delete anima;
                anima = nullptr;

                window.close();
            }

        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
```

here I am trying to launch that thread:

```
    if (launchThreads)
    {
        anima->runThread();
        launchThreads = false;
    }


        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Animation.h :

```
class Animation
{
private:
    sf::RenderWindow& window;
    sf::RectangleShape* rectPtr;

    sf::Vector2f mousePos;

    sf::Thread thread;
public:
    Animation(sf::RenderWindow& window);

    void handleEvent(sf::Event event);

    void runThread();

    void handleDraw();

    ~Animation();
};
```

and Animation.cpp :

```
Animation::Animation(sf::RenderWindow& window) : thread(&Animation::handleDraw, this), window(window),rectPtr(nullptr), mousePos()
{
    //sf::Thread thea(&handleDraw);
    //thread = thea;
    rectPtr = new sf::RectangleShape;
    rectPtr->setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
    rectPtr->setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
}

void Animation::handleEvent(sf::Event event)
{
    switch (event.type)
    {
    case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
        mousePos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseMove.x, event.mouseMove.y));
        break;
    }
}

void Animation::runThread()
{
    thread.launch();
}

void Animation::handleDraw()
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rectPtr->setPosition(i*110, 10);

        if (rectPtr->getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePos))
        {
            rectPtr->setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
        }
        else rectPtr->setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

        window.draw(*rectPtr);
    }
}

Animation::~Animation()
{
    thread.terminate();
    delete rectPtr;
    rectPtr = nullptr;

}
```

Solution:

Solved  with moving function `window.display();` inside `handleDraw()` and moving context there too by `window.setActive();` App shows what it have to. But inside console there are still same errors.. Think I can Ignore them.

Comment: Which line of code gives this error?

Comment: OT: Note that this: `: thread(&Animation::handleDraw, this)` might be a bit fragile. In your case, it's ok, but the correctness depends on the order of definition of member variables of `Animation`.

Comment: Errors are printed to the console after window.display(); from main class is executed

Comment: to be honest, I have no Idea how constructor of thread works, I found this piece of code here. And documentations makes no sence to me.

Comment: I make it works with moving function window.display(); inside handleDraw() and moving context there too by window.setActive();  App shows what it have to. But inside console there are still same errors..

Comment: I though I can have multithread rendering, but if I try to move context back to main thread, then content what should be drawn by second threat will not display.

Comment: it really depends on platform and what API you use. sfml usually wraps around OpenGl api . E.g. some platforms explicitly allow use only one thread and contexts are thread specific. but doesn't mean that several context  can be owned by several threads and they may render onto same surface. In other cases the rendering thread is a highlander, there can be only one.